# Adding add-ins to excel - strange messages

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013

I am using Excel 2010 and 2013. I would like to add an excel add-in from page http://xlloop.sourceforge.net/ . There is file with name xlloop-0.3.2 and extension Microsoft Excel XLL Add-In. I added this file from menu File -> Options -> Add-Ins -> In combobox Manage I chose Excel Add-Ins -> Go... -> Browse and I chose my file. I see the following message:

```
"C:\...\xlloop-0.3.2.xll" is not a valid add-in.
```

Thus, I do next attempt. I go from menu File -> Open -> and I chose my file. I see the message:

> The file you are trying to open "xlloop-0.3.2.xll", is in a difference
>   format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is
>   not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do
>   you want to open the file now?

After I clicked Yes I see a lot of signs (something like from Chinese)

My last attempt was double clicked on file. I see:

> The file format and extension of "xlloop-0.3.2.xll" don't match. The
>   file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't
>   open it. Do you want open it anyway?

After clicked yes I see something like the second attempt.

I am really very confused because some of my friends have the same version of Excel and they don't have these messages. Do you have any idea where is the problem in my Excel? I very need this addin to work with Java.

Comment: This sounds like a compatibility issue. Do you know the age of the add-in or what version it applies to? It does not say on the site you linked.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know. But as I wrote - some of my friends have the same version of Excel and it is working...

Comment: Are you sure the file is okay? It worked for me, SHA-1 hash is `d95a7f524d1a6838a12249717679e22664e670a5`.

Answer (score 2):

This has worked fine for me and for @DanielB (in the comments above).

As the .xll extension is just a renamed .dll, it is possible that this
[Dynamic-link library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library) refers to some package that is not installed on your computer
and therefore it cannot be loaded into Excel.

To find which package is missing, you could download the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and use it to list
all the missing references. Just be aware that some missing references are not
an error, since they refer to optional DLLs.

Let us know your results so we could compare them with ours.

[EDIT]

I have just tried adding xlloop.xll to Excel 2010 and it went perfectly well
via File -> Options -> Add-Ins.

I then tried via File -> Open and got this dialog:

[image]

So I went to "Excel Options -> Trust Center -> Macro Settings",
set to "Enable all macros" and tried again. This time it went perfectly well.
I exited and reentered Excel and checked "File -> Options -> Add-Ins" again,
and xlloop was still there. Success.

As regarding Excel 2013 : As xlloop is 32-bit, it cannot work with the 64-bit Excel.
Use the 32-bit version and do the same as above. I don't have Office 2013 and so
cannot test it myself, but I suppose that Macro Settings is even more important
in this version.

If this method doesn't work for you, you might need to install
the Visual C++ redistributable package that xlloop was compiled with.
After studying the xlloop sources, it seems that it uses the
[Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3387&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True).

Comment: I've opened xlloop.xll in Dependency Walker. What I see is here: postimg.org/image/4pcybrqkr . Is there any way to resolve this problem?

Comment: Please click in Dependency Walker on the header of the "File Time Stamp" column so all the yellow marks are sorted up front, then post another screenshot.

Comment: thanks a lof for your help. The problem is solved. I don't need lots of Microsoft Office programs (for example I don't need Power Point) thus I installed only Excel always. I uninstalled MS Office and installed again all of programs from MS Office. Now all is working. I have no idea where is the problem. By the way - now I can programming. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create a new folder and copy the xlloop-0.3.2.xll file into it.  Rename it to PythonAddIn.xll.
Then activate it in Excel.

Worked for me in Win7 SP1 X64 with Office 2013 and Python 2.7.6.

I also implemented Python function servers (using port 5454!) that works just fine.